# According to Hindu scriptures which location on earth had the first human settlements?

Tags: scripture, brahma, human

According to Hindu scriptures, after Brahma created the first humans and decided to populate the earth with early human settlements, in which geographical location did he put them. I want to know the name of the place for example Kailash mountain or Ayodhya or where? Any supporting text from scriptures would be helpful.

Comment: Kailash mountain for rudra ganas offcourse ganas also includes humans, other devtas, tribes n creatures, pretas, bhootas, etc also. The 1st humans were swayambhu Manu and Shatarupa. And their a ode was Brahmavarta.

Comment: Swami Factanand, welcome back after a long long time :)

Comment: *abode. ..

Comment: _According to Hindu scriptures.._ Be more specific because majority scriptures **do not** claim to "know" the origin of humans and universe (manusmriti is exception and not considered canonical by some). You can find a few pointers on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_cosmology.

Comment: Manu smriti is totally cononical though it has some flaws in it about caste and all which can be a result of interpolations.

Comment: @tejasvi88 Well, we cannot cannot be more specific about which scripture will answer this question. E.g. it is pointless to ask "According to Yajur Ved or the Valmiki Ramayan, where was the first settlement" because I don't know if these two sources do actually contain any relevant answer. Also Wiki is not a reliable source because anyone can edit it an cross validation of content may or may not be according to the source texts.

Comment: Om Namah Shanti...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first humans were Swayambhu Manu and Devi Shatarupa. And their abode was [Brahmavarta](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/brahmavarta). So, their kingdom should be the 1st human settlement on earth.

According to [ManuSmriti](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145593.html) 2.17-19.:

> The land created by the gods and lying between the divine rivers Saraswati and Drishadwati is called **'Brahmavarta'** - the region of Brahman. The conduct handed down from generation to generation among the social classes and the intermediate classes of that land is called the 'conduct of good people'. Kuruksetra and the lands of the Matsyas, Pancalas, and Surasenakas constitute the 'land of Brahmin seers', which borders on the Brahmavarta. All the people on earth should learn their respective practices from a Brahmin born in that land.

I hope this clarifies your queries.

Comment: This conception of human origin is fringe at best within Hinduism. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_views_on_evolution

Comment: Ur unnecessary claim is here what is fringe. Wikipedia is not considered as a proper source for this site.

Comment: Wikipedia mostly gives foraign views plus it can be edited so it cannot be taken as a proper source material. Atleast, in the case of Sanatana Dharma and anything related to it.

Comment: The concept of humans are there in sanatan dharma as the children of Manu and Shatarupa we are called as Manushya.

Comment: And majority of sanatana scriptures accept Manu and Shatarupa as the original source of humans or the 1st humans. See n Read them. Prd. Chalo. Goodbye. ..

Comment: At best here....

Comment: Om naMah Shantihi...